# Vuelidate: how to watch $v?

Tags: vue.js, vuelidate

I need to execute code when `$v.error` changes in my component, but the code within my `watch` hook is never triggered:

```
'$v.$error': {
  handler (val) {
    console.log('change detected!')
  },
  deep: true
}
```

Some relevant threads (which didn't help): [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53628450/validate-form-input-fields-in-child-component-from-a-parent-component-with-vueli) and [here](https://github.com/vuelidate/vuelidate/issues/254)

Comment: it should work  https://jsfiddle.net/3tLra97m/

Comment: Thanks! I just realized I was watching `$v` when in fact I should watch `v` (my component is receiving `v` (not `$v`) as a prop

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch for:

```
$v.value.$error
```

instead of

```
$v.$error
```

Because it is a ref